# Re-mapping the «PowerOff» key on Asus laptop keyboard under Windows 10 64 bits?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, asus-laptop, remapping

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

To re-map a laptop's power button that is absurdly placed as a key in the keyboard.

**Context:**

I have recently bought an upgraded version of ASUS VivoBook Pro N552VW laptop. It is a great machine, with great specs. I like every single detail in it, except one thing that I simply cannot swallow, nor can I understand why on Earth it exists.

A product-design genius decided that the power button to turn the computer on and off should be located among the keyboard keys. Even wiser, the genius decided that it should be placed where one usually finds the dedicated "End" key, as it can bee seen in the picture below:

[image]

**Alleviating the problem:**

While that design is obviously error prone, i.e. there is always the risk of one pressing the power key by accident and then putting the laptop to sleep in the middle of a working session. But that is easy to solve, by going to Windows' power settings and defining nothing to happen when power buttons are pressed. Se picture below:

[image]

**What remains to be done:**

However, what I would really like to do is to map such key to behave as if it were a dedicated End key again. I have tried multiple key mapping software, but none worked. I know that power keys are often mapped to the BIOS powering process at a rather low level, thus I was about to give up.

That is when I found this question at the AskUbuntu Stackoverflow: https://askubuntu.com/questions/580902/how-to-change-mapping-for-the-poweroff-key-on-keyboard

There, a solution is given for Ubuntu OS. It then gave me back hope that doing the same under windows might be possible. Therefore, my question here: how could I properly re-map the silly Asus power button to behave as if it were an "End" key?

My preferred solution would be doing that via Windows registry. Only if that is not possible at all I would like to experiment the option of using external re-mapping softwares that have to be loaded all time.

**What have I tried exactly:**

I have actually tried both changing the registry and also using external software. No free software that I could find allowed me to properly re-map the power key.

Changing the registry, the best I could find out is to make NumLock key become the End key (then NumLock would be accessed by Ctrl+Alt+PauseBreak):

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
>
> "Scancode Map"= 00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,4f,e0,45,00,45,00,46,e0,00,00,00,00

Needless to say, this stands out as a rather dirty solution since it creates more mess.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help, except to support your notion that this is a messed up keyboard design.

Comment: Use [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases) to see if the Power key generates a scan-code ([tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)). If it doesn't have one, then it cannot be mapped, only disabled just as you did. The most you can do is reset it back to do power-down and then trap that event, but this is more trouble than it's worth. Note: Sometimes a long press on this button is the only way to shut down a hanged computer in a semi-orderly manner.

Comment: you haven't seen a Mac or other laptops with power key on the keyboard? Old Macs even have DVD eject key on the keyboard. And no, you can't remap the key if it's processed by the keyboard firmware and doesn't generate any scancode, just like you generally can't remap Fn key on Windows. Duplicate: [Can I remap the Power key to the End key on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1262161/241386)

Comment: [Hook system power button in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392653/995714), [How can I intercept the push of the physical power button in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14593834/995714), [Run a program on: hard “Power” button press](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48285507/995714)

Comment: duplicate of [Can the power button of a PC or laptop be remapped?](https://superuser.com/q/907609/241386), unfortunate it can't be closed due to the bounty

Answer (score 5):

Use
[SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases)
to see if the Power key generates a scan-code on your keyboard.
If it does, then SharpKeys can remap the key in the registry which will
work for all programs.
See for tutorial the article
[Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/).

In the case that the Power key doesn't generate a scan-code under Windows,
then it cannot be mapped, only disabled just as you did.
Even if Linux can remap it because it affords
better control over the keyboard, this is then not the case for Windows.

The most you can do in this case is to reactivate the Power key and reset it
back to do again power-down, and then trap and cancel that event,
remapping it to another key such as the <kbd>End</kbd> key.
This can be done by using
[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/),
but may be more trouble than it's worth.
If you are interested I can expand my answer to show how this is done.

I do note that sometimes using the Power button is the only way to
shut down a hanged computer in a semi-orderly manner.

Comment: If you are referring to the shutdown prevention script in [AHK:OnMessage](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm), note that **"this is reported NOT to work on Windows Vista and later"**. Else I'd like to see your magic.

Comment: @guest: There are several such scripts to be found. I believe that an API program can cancel the shutdown, no magic involved, so AHK should be able to do it too. But as I said, this might not be worth the trouble of pointing the poster at these links and asking him to invest his time in checking them out, as these solutions may not be guaranteed to work for all cases.