# Re-mapping NumLock key to behave as the End key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, button-remapping

I happen to be in a similar situation to that of the unfortunate soul who posted this question: [Re-mapping the «PowerOff» key on Asus laptop keyboard under Windows 10 64 bits?](https://superuser.com/questions/1244209/re-mapping-the-poweroff-key-on-asus-laptop-keyboard-under-windows-10-64-bits). That is, I have a laptop whose keyboard does not have an `End` dedicated key.

I really want for it to have, and so I started searching online for how to remap my `NumLock` key to become the `End` key. In the above linked question, the OP mentions that she had found a way to do so by going to the Windows registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
```

And then adding the following binary value:

```
"Scancode Map"= 00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,4f,e0,45,00,45,00,46,e0,00,00,00,00
```

I tried just that, as can be seen in the following partial screen-shot:

[(link to image, since I don't have enough rep to embed images within questions'bodies)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvSha.png)

Yet, the trick does not work for me. I have a Windows 10 64bits, up-to-date with all updates. I wonder, what could be wrong? How could I make it work and achieve the desired re-mapping **via changing the Windows Registry**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

some gaming keyboards/ laptops come with software that can change the mapping of the keys. this would be the simplest solution.

if you don't have such software auto hotkey is a simple free tool with witch you can write simple code that can do various things such as remapping or even opening programs. its really easy and there is lots of documentation/video tutorials online. if it cant be done auto hotkey is your man/woman/software...

Answer (score 0):

uncap! - https://github.com/susam/uncap#features

Usage:

Map Caps Lock key to Left Control key.

```
uncap 0x14:0xa2
```

The following list briefly describes some of the features of Uncap.

Map Caps Lock key to Escape key on a new Windows system with almost no effort. Just download and double-click. This is the primary reason why Uncap was written. This tool was written for users of vi editor who like to map their Caps Lock key to Escape key for convenience.

Map any key to any key, multiple keys to other keys, or disable keys using command line arguments. No additional file or script is required.

Enable, disable or modify key mappings without having to reboot the Windows system.
Disable key mappings easily by stopping Uncap.

It is a single-file executable. It is very lightweight. The executable is only about 100 KB in size. It occupies less than 1 MB of memory and negligible CPU while running.

Answer (score 0):

[sharpkeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) is probably the best and most easy to use software for this.