# Can I remap the Power key to the End key on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have this new Zenbook with the following keyboard config:

[image]

If you look carefully in the top right corner, you can see the keys

`Home` `PgUp` `PgDn` and `POWER` keys

This is driving me crazy, I frequently use the `End` key but on this keyboard, it is the Power button instead!

From the control panel, I already changed the Power button to do nothing so I don't shutdown my computer inadvertently. But I want my `End` key back! Is there any way I can get the Power button to act as the End key?

I tried SharpKeys without success as it does not detect that key code...

Comment: It isn’t a keyboard button it’s a power button, QED, so it can’t be mapped to be a keyboard button.  You can use software to capture the keyboard signals to confirm my statement

Comment: does that mean impossible? ;_;

Comment: My comment seems clear. I will let someone else submit an actual answer

Comment: what did Asus think, removing essential keys like that >_<

Comment: Perhaps they copied an excellent design : looking at that pic it looks very similar the macbook pro layout I am working on....

Comment: ahah yes I agree they copied it though I disagree it is an excellent design...

Comment: mine has the speakers on each side of the keyboard so I am happy with my choice and I don't find the position of the keys a problem....

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/907609/can-the-power-button-of-a-pc-or-laptop-be-remapped) answer